# How to delay php submit, but not javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
if (isset($_POST['post'])) {    
    if ($mSecs >= .54075102806091) {
        echo "Have A Good Day!";    
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
            'spinWheel.startAnimation();',
            '</script>';
        sleep(4);
    } else {
        echo "Other";
        echo '<script type="text/Javascript">',
            'spinWheel1.startAnimation();',
            '</script>';
        sleep(4);
    }
}
```

I am trying to delay the submission of the php form, but still run the javascript annimation. The sleep feature delays the submission, but it also delays the javascript... Any ideas on how to delay the submission of the php from without delaying the javascript annimation? Thanks for all responses

Comment: what you can do is use ajax with javascript `seTimeOut()`. remember php is server side. So it is going to get executed before js. especially when you use it as `isset($_POST)`

Comment: I would add a done function to that animation, and submit the form after the animation.

Comment: why don't you do the delay in javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

A simplest thing you can do to delay the process, for me I think is to create a loop inside the isset(),

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){

  // do something

}
```